# How to determine image of the fundamental group of a covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

Consider the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ in $(1)$. Then distinct loops in $(1)$ are represented by $\langle a, b^2, bab^{-1} \rangle$.

Thus elements of the fundamental group are words generated by these distinct loops.

This fundamental group will map to a subgroup $H$ of $\pi_1( S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ under the covering map.

With this covering map, I think, $a \mapsto a$, $bab^{-1} \mapsto a$ and $b^2 \mapsto b^2$.

I can't quite put this information together to determine $H$. My guess would be $\langle a, b^2 \rangle$ but I am not quite sure if this is correct.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

1)is $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ its fundamental group is $Z*Z*Z$ and it is the subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$ generated by $a,b^2,bab^{-1}$.